# Using Junction object to display related list

Tags: related-list, custom, object, junction-object

Problem: I need to create a way to view two related fields on a given record between two different custom objects. I have looked up junction objects and it seems that this will be the best solution. So far I have created the junction object (PA by Proc Code) with a master-detail relationship between the two objects (PA and Proc Code). In a specific PA record, the junction object shows up in the related lists section, but will not display data. I am stuck and do not know how to go further.

I am still very new to Salesforce, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have two objects, PA and Proc Code, that are in a many-to-many relationship with one another. On one or both of these objects, you would like to show a Related List of the other and include on that Related List specific fields from the other object.

If that's the case, all you need to do is, on the Page Layout for your primary object (PA or Proc), edit the Related List for the junction object. You should see fields from *both* parent objects available for selection: just pick the ones you need.

(Screenshot from an NPSP page layout).

[image: Screenshot from NPSP]

Comment: Yes, your description is correct. When I am in the page layout, I am only seeing the available fields for Proc Code and PA by Proc Code junction object. There are no available fields to chose from PA. I am sure I am doing something incorrect, but I am unsure of what.

Comment: @LeahG Do you definitely have a Master-Detail relationship from "PA By Proc Code" to _both_ parent objects?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Looks like the solution is to ensure you have Master Detail Relationship fields on your junction object. NOT A LOOKUP RELATIONSHIP field. That was my mistake.